# Aggregate count based on column identifier

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with this structure and with a variable with identifiers such as "q1_att_brand":

```
id q1_1_1  q1_1_2  q1_2_1  q1_2_2
1  1       1       1       1  
2          1       1       1
3  1                       1
4  1               1       1
5  1               1       1
```

How can I get the combination of values in another df such as:

```
      brand1  brand2
att1  4       2
att2  4       5
```

Basically getting the combinations of atts and brands.

Thx.

Comment: Hey, I managed to optimize my answer a bit, feel free to take a look if you're interested. Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn your columns into a multi-index, then use sum and unstack:

```
# Do this step if "id" is not already the index
# df = df.set_index('id')

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    (f'att{a}', f'brand{b}') for _, a, b in df.columns.str.split('_'))

df.sum().unstack()

      brand1  brand2
att1     4.0     2.0
att2     4.0     5.0
```

---

**Let's take a closer look:**

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    (f'att{a}', f'brand{b}') for _, a, b in df.columns.str.split('_'))
```

yields,

```
   brand1 brand2 brand1 brand2
id                            
1     1.0    1.0    1.0      1
2     NaN    1.0    1.0      1
3     1.0    NaN    NaN      1
4     1.0    NaN    1.0      1
5     1.0    NaN    1.0      1
```

From here, we sum all columns,

```
df.sum()

att1  brand1    4.0
      brand2    2.0
att2  brand1    4.0
      brand2    5.0
```

Finally, reshape the result to look like the expected output.

```
_.unstack()  # same as unstack(level=-1)

      brand1  brand2
att1     4.0     2.0
att2     4.0     5.0
```